# Implement property source precedence in Spring Cloud Config Server client

Tags: java, spring-cloud-config

I need to implement client code in java for using spring cloud config server.  The client side is not a spring app nor a web service.

We will have an application.properties file.  We will have an app-specific file.  And we will have environment-specific files for both of them.  My understanding of spring config precedence rules is that the precedence, from lowest to highest should be:

```
application.properties (lowest)
specificApp.properties
application-dev.properties
specificApp-dev.properties (highest)
```

However, when I call the service with http://localhost:8888/specifcApp/dev, the property sources are returned in the opposite order from the above:

```
0: specificApp-dev.properties
1: application-dev.properties
2: specificApp.properties
3: application.properties
```

I am not certain, but I believe that the intention is that the order returned indicates the precedence from lowest to highest (the last one wins).  If that is true, then this is indicating that application.properties has precedence over the others.  That is the opposite of what I would expect.

I have yet to find spring documentation that covers this completely all in one location.  There is confusing information scattered around.  But in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) document, it says, "...profile-specific files always [override] the non-specific ones, whether or not the profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

What are the actual precedence rules, and what does the order of the property sources in the response indicate?

The second part of the question is, how can I iterate over the configService property sources in ANY order?

I found the sample code below.  However, the problem is that CompositePropertySource.getPropertySources() returns a Collection.  In other words, there is no way to get an ordered list from CompositePropertySource.  (The sources are stored internally in CompositePropertySource in a Set.)

```
        final CompositePropertySource compositePropertySource 
            = (CompositePropertySource)environment.getPropertySources().get("configService");

        if (compositePropertySource != null && compositePropertySource.getPropertySources() != null) {

            // compositePropertySource.getPropertySources() is not ordered!
            for (final Object mapPropertySourceObject : compositePropertySource.getPropertySources()) {
                final MapPropertySource propertySource = (MapPropertySource)mapPropertySourceObject;

                if (propertySource != null) {
                    p.putAll(propertySource.getSource());
                    LOG.info("fetched remote properties");
                }
            }
        }
```

To summarize:

1. What is the precedence rule supposed to be?
2. What does the order of property sources indicate in the Json raw server response?
3. How can I access the actual order of the property sources that make up the configService composite property source?

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Edgware.SR4.

**Edit**: I see now that the CompositePropertySource propertySources set is of type 
LinkedHashSet, so it does have an order.  And CompositePropertySource.getPropertyNames(), it's clear that properties from property sources later in the list will override those earlier in the list. If that's true, then application.properties takes precedence over the app- or profile-specific configurations.  I don't see how that can be the expected behavior.  It means that no property can be overridden, in effect.

**Edit #2**: I am testing this using a Git repo.  All four of the files are in the same folder within the repo.

**Edit #3**: I realized some properties influence this.  When I submitted this, I should have stated that I was launching the client with JVM options: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.profiles.default=dev and -Dspring.cloud.config.profile=dev.  I also tried it with just -Dspring.cloud.config.profile=dev.

**Update**: I am closer to a solution.

I tried the following:

1. Rename application.properties to application-default.properties.
2. Rename specificApp.properties to specificApp-default.properties.
3. Then I ran with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,default.  I had no             -Dspring.profiles.default property and no -Dspring.cloud.config.profile property.

In this case, they were returned in this order:

```
specificApp-default.properties
application-default.properties
specificApp-dev.properties
application-dev.properties
```

This is still not what I would expect.  It means that the shared application properties will override (i.e. take precedence over) the appSpecific properties.  I would expect the following order, but am getting closer to a solution, I think:

```
application-default.properties
specificApp-default.properties
application-dev.properties
specificApp-dev.properties
```

or even this order:

```
application-default.properties
application-dev.properties
specificApp-default.properties
specificApp-dev.properties
```